# Position of subtitles when casting video

Tags: android, casting, google-cast, subtitle

I have an Android application for playing movies via Googlecast. Some movies contain subtitles. It is no problem to turn subtitles on. I am using `List` of `MediaTrack` class and it works great.

I found out that position of subtitles in television is sometimes different. I am casting some movie and some sentences in subtitles are in different position. It is hard to explain in detail, so let me show two images, which make it clear.

[image: Sometimes, subtitles are here]

[image: But sometimes, subtitles are in different position (below)]

Does anybody know what affects the position of subtitles and eventually is there any option how can I change the position?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you loading a subtitle track as well or are the subtitles part of the movie?

Comment: @not_a_bot Subtitles are not the part of movie. I load track with subtitle. The movie does not contain hard-coded subtitles.

Comment: What kind of receiver are you using?

Comment: @not_a_bot I am using custom receiver with support of DRM.

Comment: You could try editing the webvtt files to only show up where you want them to as seen here: http://html5doctor.com/video-subtitling-and-webvtt/ (check under "Styling Options).

Comment: @not_a_bot Thanks, but I don't use any styles in my .vtt files.